# How to add a css class to an Angular AbstractControl

Tags: javascript, angular

*I'm new to angular and have been searching for a solution to this problem with no luck, I would really appreciate your help.*

I have a a FormGroup object with a list of controls, based on some criteria, I then select a specific control as per below.

```
// someForm : FormGroup
var target = this.someForm.get(targetControlName); // AbstractControl
```

OR

```
var target = this.someForm.controls[targetControlName]; // AbstractControl
```

I want to add a css class to this target control. Something this

```
target.AddCssClass("someClass");
```

I've tried this solution but it didn't work.

```
(<any>this.someForm.get(targetControlName)).nativeElement.classList.add('someCssClass');
```

Angular CLI: 9.1.15
Node: 14.19.0

Comment: `FormControl` is not an Element, so there's no option to add a class to it... why not add it to the template?

Comment: @EliPorush thanks for the comment, that would work. however, the template contains a lot of elements and that would require me to change each and everyone of them. 

I would hoping there is a way to cast the `FornControl` and treat it as an element.

Comment: " that would require me to change each and everyone of them" - why? maybe you should explain the scenario a little better - what is the condition you want to change the CSS for? and also share your template with us, it'll help